# G is a commutative group of order 2*N, how to prove G has a N-order quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group

> $G$ is a commutative group of order $2N$, how to prove $G$ has a $N$-order quotient group?

Now I know $G$ must has two subgroup, one is order $N$ and another is order $2$; now what should do to prove it has a $N$-order quotient group?

Comment: Well if you factor out that subgroup of order $2$ you claim to have, how big is the quotient you get?

Comment: The subgroup of order $N$ has index $2$.  Do you know anything interesting about subgroups of index $2$?

Answer (score 1):

By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. Now by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) we have

$$[G:H]\cdot |H|=|G|$$

meaning $[G:H]=N$. Finally since $G$ is commutative then $H$ is normal and so $G/H$ is a quotient group of order $|G/H|=[G:H]$